# python: for loop outputing incorect float

Tags: python, list, for-loop, range

So I wrote this function to generate a list of numbers between `start` and `stop` (inclusively) at `step` interval:

```
start, stop, step, = -3, 3, 0.1
print [x * step + start for x in range(int((stop + step - start) / step))]
print 12 * 0.1 + -3
```

the output was:

```
[1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7000000000000002, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0]
1.7
```

why is the list messing up 1.7, but when I do the same operation outside the for loop, it works just fine?  How do I fix the for loop?

Comment: Printing a single value in Python 2.7 uses `str(x)` which does rounding. Printing a list uses `repr(x)` which doesn't round. Both operations are returning the same value, you're just printing them differently.

Comment: @Mark Ransom that is really helpful. Thank you.  So is there a way to make the values in the list exact?

Comment: I'm afraid there is not, that's why you were directed to the other question. If you go through all those answers you should start to understand.